# Match returning a string instead of object

Tags: javascript, function, match, matching

This simple regex matching returns a string instead of an object on every browser but the latest firefox...

```
        text = "language. Filename: My Old School Yard.avi. File description: File size: 701.54 MB. View on Megavideo. Enter this, here:"
    name = text.match(/(Filename:)(.*) File /);
    alert(typeof(name));
```

as far as i know this the match function is suppose to return an object (Array).
Has anyone come across this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RegExp [`match`](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-15.5.4.10) method does return an array, but arrays in JavaScript are simply objects that inherit from `Array.prototype`, e.g.:

```
var array = "foo".match(/foo/); // or [];,  or new Array();

typeof array; // "object"
array instanceof Array; // true
Object.prototype.toString.call(array); // "[object Array]"
```

The [`typeof`](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-11.4.3) operator will return `"object"` because it can't distinguish between an ordinary object and an array.

In the second line I use the `instanceof` operator to prove that the object is actually an array, but this operator has [known issues](http://perfectionkills.com/instanceof-considered-harmful-or-how-to-write-a-robust-isarray/) when working in cross-frame environments.

In the third line I use the [`Object.prototype.toString`](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-15.2.4.2) method, which returns a string that contains the [`[[Class]]`](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-8.6.2) internal property, this property is a value that indicates the *kind* of the object, a much safer way to detect if an object is an array or not.